# Grails object marshalling - adding data type hints?

Tags: forms, grails, groovy, marshalling

I'd like to be able to have something like this:

```
<form>
<input type="date" name="params.date"/>
<input type="text" name="params.myString"/>
</form>
```

And marshall this to

```
Map<String, Object> params
   ['date': (Date object),
    'myString': (String)]
```

inside of a command object holder as such:

```
class Holder{
   def params
   def unshownAttributes
}
```

I thought about doing some hackery involving javascript to parse out a `data-type` HTML5 attribute and preprending the name (and fixing up the types later), but I was hoping there was a better way to do this automatically with groovy or grails.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I may understand what you're after now. Your `params` map is supposed to be just a map of the possible form elements from an HTML form, not `params` as used in a grails controller action (i.e. request parameters). Is that correct? I think your naming (using `params`) is what's confusing me.

Comment: If that *is* the case, do you want your map to instead be a `Map<String, Class>`? e.g. `Map<String, Class> fields = ['date': Date.class, 'myString': String.class]`?

Comment: @Rob: I'm pretty sure either syntax would work, and the concept is the same. Either I need params.blah to be of arbitrary type, or technically params.params.blah (which in my case is a command object):

class CommandObject{ def params, def otherAttributes }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such mechanism currently exists. You may save yourself some pain by just creating methods for every marshalling instance you need with proper command objects.